# Django app - Browse a dictionary with sub arrays

Tags: python, django

I would like to browse and display this dictionary which contains other sub-tables inside
Here I would like to display the purchases of "fafa" only
Views.py

```
def app(request):
 dict= {
    "toto": "tata",
    "messages": [
  {
   "mont": "ton",
   "fafa": "fki"
  }
],
 "commandes": [
  {
  "numero": "h221g",
  "date": "14-07-22",
  "reference": "ref1",
  "name": "fafa",
  "purchases": [
    {
      "article": "articlename",
      "designation": "laptop",
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": 133
    },
    {
       "article":"article2",
       "designation":"Dell"
       "quantity":3,
       "price":144
    },
    ...
  ]
 },
 ....
]
}
 mes_ventes=dict['commandes']
 purchases=dict['commandes'][0]['purchases']
 context={'commandes':mes_ventes,'lignes':purchases}
 return render(request,'test/test.html',context)
```

test.html

```
{% for commande in commandes %}
    {% if commande.name == "fafa" %}
        {% for ligne in lignes %}
            <p>{{ligne.article}}<br>{{ligne.designation}}<br>
                {{ligne.quantity}}<br>
            {{ligne.price}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I get purchases but not those of "fafa"

Comment: `dict` is a bad name for your variable, when you define that you are [shadowing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-shadowing-in-python/) the built in dictionary constructor

Comment: you pass `mes_lignes` as a context var but `mes_lignes` is not defined in the code in the question

Comment: why not do `{% for purchase in commande.purchases %}` instead of `{% for ligne in lignes %}`

Comment: or get rid of `{% if commande.name == "fafa" %}` in the template - you already have `purchases=dict['commandes'][0]['purchases']` in the view, so just pass `purchases` as context to the template

Comment: @Anentropique It was a typo, I corrected it.

Comment: I think the error comes from purchases=dict['commandes'][0]['purchases']
, does this allow me to browse the purchase sub-array

Comment: yes that should return the purchases list for the first commande

Comment: And how to return the order of any user with a different name

Comment: where does the dict come from?  why not request only the data for the person you want to display?